# RequestLogger's response is not updated in case of exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mdc

I have setup a filter following way:

```java
public class RequestLogger extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                 HttpServletResponse response, 
                                 FilterChain chain) 
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            insertRequestInfoIntoMDC(request); 
            chain.doFilter(request, response); // <-- NPE thrown
        } finally {
            MDC.put(response_status, String.valueOf(response.getStatus())) // <-- response.getStatus() is 200
            log.info(createMessage(request));
            clearMDC();
        }
    }
```

When there is an exception thrown, the log message from the "finally" block logs status 200, however, the actual response status is 500.

There is also an exception, which is logged by `org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/path].[dispatcherServlet]`:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/path] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
```

It is also worth mentioning, that there is no global exception handler defined in the app, as for such exceptions the `response` object has the proper status code.

I would expect that after `chain.doFilter()` is executed, the `response` object should have a proper (HTTP500) statusCode, but it's not.